Openlayers 4.6.4 version vector layer with 150 features not working when we dynamically set text only in Chrome laptop/ PC
I have map with a layer consists of more than 150 features. I'm setting text dynamically for each features. For some reason, the texts are not rendered as expected only in Google Chrome of laptop. I'm not sure what causes this problem.
I use windows 10/11 PC

Below is my code
this.dockLayer = new OlVectorLayer({
      style: (f, r) => this.styleDockFunction(f, r),
      source: new OlVector({})
    });


styleDockFunction(feature: OlFeature, resolution) {
    let data = feature.get("data");
    //let color = MapExtension.getStationTickFeatureColor(data);
    let styles = MapExtension.getLargeDockingStationStyles(
      false,
      data,
      this.isMobileOnly
    );
    let text = "";
    // if (resolution < 19) {
    text = MapExtension.getFeatureName(feature);
    // };
    styles[1].getText().setText(text);
    if (resolution > 19) {
      styles[1].getImage().setScale(0.7);
      styles[1].getText().setScale(0.7);
      styles[1].getText().setOffsetY(2);
    }
    return styles;
  }

static getLargeDockingStationStyles(highlighted: boolean = false, data, isMobile: boolean = false): OlStyle[] {
    let featureColor = highlighted ? '#FF2C00' : '#04A3E3';
    let color = data.StationStatus;
    if (color) {
      featureColor = color;
    }
    let imageRadius = highlighted ? 2 : 2;
    let strokeWidth = highlighted ? 2 : 2;

    let styles = [
      // polygon
      new OlStyle({
        stroke: new OlStroke({
          color: featureColor,
          width: strokeWidth
        })
      }),
      new OlStyle({
        image: new OlIcon(({
          src: data["dockIcon"],
          rotation: 0,
          rotateWithView: true,
          scale: (isMobile) ? 1.2 : 1.5
        })),
        text: new OlText({
          font: `18px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif`,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
          placement: 'point',
          fill: new OlFill({
            color: 'white'
          })
        })
      })
    ]
    return styles;
  }

I have no clue what causes this issue. This worked fine around last December and this issue have started only this year. Can someone help me to find a working solution for this? I checked chatgpt and nothing works for me

Edit you question and add info about OS of PC.

@TomazicM updated I use windows

Could not replicate this behavior on Windows 10. Did you try to experiment with different fonts? What about the text content? Is it clean?

Have a look at this: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15134

@TomazicM I found a solution this is an issue with chrome flags. I will update the answer here shortly. Thanks for helping out

I finally found out the issue is related to "Accelerated 2D canvas" chrome flag which is by default enabled in the chrome browser. This flag enables the use of the GPU to perform 2d canvas rendering instead of using software rendering.
As far as I remember, in Laptops/PCs GPU is disabled by default. However, Android/iOS phones have GPU enabled hardware (now a days). That is the reason why it was working on phones and tablets.
I have disabled the "Accelerated 2D canvas" chrome flag and now the map fonts are working as expected.
Steps to disable "Accelerated 2D canvas" flag

Open URL chrome://flags/ and search for "Accelerated 2D canvas"
Disable the flag if Enabled and relaunch the browser

Refer the below images for additional info



